# Convert string to hex values in micropython

Tags: python, micropython

I have input of "0013A20041E0E0A8" and i need to convert it to hex values or bytestring for example b'\x00\x13\xa2\x00\x41\xE0\xE0\xa8'. I read it from UART as a bytes. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `ubinascii.unhexlify` function.

```
import ubinascii
.....
bytesValues = ubinascii.unhexlify(hexstring)
```